# Why do my Tkinter program's UI elements shake when text boxes are generated whilst disabled and hidden?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a `diceware` app. There's an option to generate hidden words. When it's off, the words generate normally, but when it's on, the words' text boxes (along with some UI buttons) appear to shake.

diceware_gui.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import customtkinter

import password_generation.diceware_logic as logic



class DicewareToplevel(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    """
    This class creates the diceware toplevel window and its contents.
    """
    def __init__(self, master: customtkinter.CTkToplevel, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.password_state = 'shown'

        self.checkboxes_text = {}

        self.widget_text_dict = {}

        # Give a weight to rows 0 to 15
        i = 0
        while i <= 15:
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='row')
            i += 1

        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792555/why-is-there-extra-space-after-the-last-column-in-a-tkinter-application
        # That question helped me out a TON!
        # Give a weight to columns 0 to 9
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 2, 4, 6, 8), weight=1, uniform="a")
        self.grid_columnconfigure((1, 3, 5, 7, 9), uniform="b")

        self.word_font = customtkinter.CTkFont(family=self.font_name, size=12)
        self.button_font = customtkinter.CTkFont(family=self.font_name, size=24)

        self.output_widgets = []
        self.text_widgets = []

        self.number_of_dicerolls = 0

        self.roll_dice_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, border_width=self.button_border_width,
                                                        border_color=self.button_border_colour, text='ROLL DICE',
                                                        font=self.button_font, fg_color=self.button_fg_color,
                                                        hover_color=self.button_hover_color,
                                                        command=lambda: display_words(logic.roll_dice()))
        self.roll_dice_button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.button_columnspan, sticky='n')

        self.shown_passwords_text = 'PASSWORDS ARE: SHOWN'

        def clear_window() -> None:
            """
            This function clears the window of any output widgets.
            """
            self.widget_text_dict = {}

            for widget in self.output_widgets:
                widget.destroy()

            self.output_widgets = []
            self.checkboxes_text = {}

            self.password_state = 'shown'
            self.hide_show_button.configure(text=self.shown_passwords_text, command=hide_passwords)

            self.number_of_dicerolls = 0

        self.clear_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text='CLEAR', command=clear_window)
        self.clear_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=self.button_columnspan, sticky='n')

        def insert_text(textbox: customtkinter.CTkTextbox, text: str) -> None:
            textbox.configure(state='normal')
            textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
            textbox.insert('1.0', text)
            textbox.configure(state='disabled')
            textbox.bind('<Button-3>', show_copy_menu)
            self.widget_text_dict[textbox] = text

        def display_words(pair: dict) -> None:
            text_height = 1
            text_padx = 10

            if self.number_of_dicerolls < 35:
                column_to_be_placed_in = (self.number_of_dicerolls % 5) * 2
                self.number_of_dicerolls += 1
                (diceroll, word), = pair.items()

                self.diceroll_widget = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self)
                self.diceroll_widget.grid(row=2 + 2 * ((self.number_of_dicerolls - 1) // 5),
                                          column=column_to_be_placed_in,
                                          pady=(5, 0))
                insert_text(self.diceroll_widget, str(diceroll))
                self.output_widgets.append(self.diceroll_widget)
                self.text_widgets.append(self.diceroll_widget)

                self.word_widget = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, font=self.word_font, height=text_height)
                self.word_widget.grid(row=3 + 2 * ((self.number_of_dicerolls - 1) // 5),
                                      column=column_to_be_placed_in,
                                      pady=(0, 5))
                insert_text(self.word_widget, word)
                self.output_widgets.append(self.word_widget)
                self.text_widgets.append(self.word_widget)

                self.checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self,
                                                          text='',
                                                          checkbox_width=20, width=0,
                                                          checkbox_height=20, fg_color='gray',
                                                          hover_color=('grey', 'white'))
                self.checkbox.grid(row=3 + 2 * ((self.number_of_dicerolls - 1) // 5), column=column_to_be_placed_in + 1,
                                   sticky='w')
                self.output_widgets.append(self.checkbox)
                self.checkboxes_text[self.word_widget.get('1.0', 'end')] = self.checkbox
                if self.password_state == 'hidden':
                    hide_passwords()
            else:
                answer = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Dice roll limit reached',
                                                   'You have reached the maximum limit of 35 dice rolls. Do you want '
                                                   'to clear the screen?', parent=self)
                if answer == 'yes':
                    clear_window()

        self.copy_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text='COPY SELECTIONS', command=lambda: logic.copy_selections(self.checkboxes_text))
        self.copy_button.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=self.button_columnspan, pady=10, sticky='n')

        def show_passwords() -> None:
            """
            Called when the user clicks the show button,
            this function shows all passwords.
            """
            if self.widget_text_dict != {}:
                for widget, text in self.widget_text_dict.items():
                    widget.configure(state='normal')
                    widget.insert('0.0', text)
                    widget.configure(state='disabled')
            self.password_state = 'shown'
            self.hide_show_button.configure(text=self.shown_passwords_text, command=hide_passwords)

        def hide_passwords() -> None:
            """
            Called when the user clicks the hide button,
            this function hides all passwords.
            """
            for widget, text in self.widget_text_dict.items():
                widget.configure(state='normal')
                if widget.get('1.0', 'end') != '\n':
                    text = widget.get('1.0', 'end')
                widget.delete('0.0', 'end')
                widget.configure(state='disabled')
            self.password_state = 'hidden'
            self.hide_show_button.configure(text='PASSWORDS ARE: HIDDEN', command=show_passwords)

        self.hide_show_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, border_width=self.button_border_width,
                                                        border_color=self.button_border_colour,
                                                        text=self.shown_passwords_text,
                                                        font=self.button_font, fg_color=self.button_fg_color,
                                                        hover_color=self.button_hover_color,
                                                        command=hide_passwords)
        self.hide_show_button.grid(row=17, column=0, columnspan=self.button_columnspan, pady=10, sticky='n')

        self.withdraw()
        self.after(200, self.show_icon)

        def close_second_window() -> None:
            """
            This function destroys the window when it is closed.
            """
            self.destroy()
            self.master.deiconify()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_second_window)

    def show_icon(self) -> None:
        """
        This function shows the icon of the toplevel window.
        """
        self.deiconify()
        self.iconbitmap('textures/logo.ico')
```

diceware_logic.py:

```
import secrets
import clipboard
from tkinter import TclError

from password_generation.wordlist import wordlist as wordlist

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def roll_dice() -> dict:
    final_pairs = {}
    dice_roll = ''

    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        dice_roll += str(secrets.choice(numbers))
        i += 1

    final_pairs[dice_roll] = wordlist[dice_roll]
    return final_pairs


def copy_selected_text(labels: list) -> None:
    try:
        for label in labels:
            selected_text = str(label.selection_get())
            clipboard.copy(selected_text)
    except (ValueError, TclError):
        # There is no need to warn the user when they try to copy nothing as it does not have any effect on the app
        pass


def copy_selections(checkboxes_text_boxes: dict) -> None:
    text_to_be_copied = ''
    for key, value in checkboxes_text_boxes.items():
        if value.get() == 1:
            text_to_be_copied += key
    # Get rid of line-breaks and spaces
    text_to_be_copied = text_to_be_copied.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
    clipboard.copy(text_to_be_copied)
```

I tried finding the cause of it, but I can't understand what's so different about generating those text boxes whilst hidden that makes them shake.

Comment: That was a pretty lengthy program. You think you could maybe isolate the problem better?

Comment: I'll remove some functions I think are unrelated to this issue.

Comment: I don't see import `diceware_logic` and `diceware_gui`. How do I know which one to execute script?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Look at the top of `diceware_gui.py`, underneath `import customtkinter`. It has an import statement that says `import password_generation.diceware_logic as logic`.

Comment: Please try to reduce the size of the code, and make it a single block.